# discord.py - Why have my commands stopped working?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have used these commands before and they were fully functional and I have
`discord.Intents.all()` enabled as well.

All these do is send song lyrics one after another, so it's pretty simple.
Recently however, these commands have ceased to do anything at all.
I have;

- checked if the intents are enabled on the developer portal
- consulted the API reference
- rearranged the positions of the commands in my code
- checked the member list in the channel I was using to test the commands.

Also included is `on_message()` because I have heard that it can interfere with the rest of the bot's commands.
The process commands method didn't work either.

I hope it's not something really simple I've missed.

```
import asyncio
import os

import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
GUILD = os.getenv("DISCORD_GUILD")

goofbot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='TBIH', intents=discord.Intents.all())

soslyrics = {
    1: "I be comin like an autobahn",
    2: "I'm murdering everything",
    3: "I'm a killer with a mission to flip it",
    4: "I'm sick with it give her the lip",
    5: "and I be itchin' to give it",
    6: "a whiff of the wicked",
    7: "and I stick it with the crick",
    8: "and they diggin it",
    9: "DROP",
    10: "Like I said it before",
    11: "Imma get up and go and get it",
    12: "because I'm Mr. Malignant",
    13: "Keepin you riveted",
    14: "livin' it polygamist sin a bit",
    15: "any chick in a minute Tecca N9na be kickin it",
    16: "I flow from the Middle West",
    17: "Go for your little neck",
    18: "Don't let me get it,",
    19: "but yo' ho?",
    20: "Imma get her wet",
    21: "Stop and drop on top a twat",
    22: "in yo' kitchen",
    23: "Not the guap I pop",
    24: "without an admission",
    25: "Hailing from Missouri",
    26: "You can smell out the hell in the thizzery",
    27: "Just remember me",
    28: "Bustin deliveries",
    29: "and I'm makin it shivery",
    30: "I'm takin my little city to lyrical liberty",
    31: "I go for the gust",
    32: "Don't leave the ground",
    33: "No bush to beat around",
    34: "All the Midwest Choppers on this track",
    35: "and \"yes sir, we are DOWN\"",
    36: "Tecca N9na with Bone",
    37: "everybody gets on",
    38: "other MC's we are clown",
    39: "And we do it like the bullet from a gun, or better yet",
    40: "THE SPEED OF SOUND!"
}

sslyrics = {
    1: "She sells sea shells on the sea shore",
    2: "but the value of those shells will fall",
    3: "Due to the laws of supply and demand",
    4: "No one wants to buy shells cause there's loads on the sand!",
    5: "Step 1: You must create a sense of scarcity",
    6: "Shells will sell much better if the people think they're rare you see",
    7: "Bare with me",
    8: "Take as many shells as you can find and hide them on an island",
    9: "Stockpile em high until they're rarer than a diamond",
    10: "Step 2: You gotta make the people think that they want em",
    12: "Really want em, really fuckin' want em",
    13: "Hit em like Bronson",
    14: "Influencers, product placement, featured prime-time entertainment",
    15: "If you haven't got a shell then you're just a fuckin' waste, man",
    16: "Step 3: It's monopoly",
    17: "Invest inside some property",
    18: "Start a corporation, make a logo, do it properly",
    19: "These shells must sell, that will be your new philosophy",
    20: "Swallow all your morals, they're a poor man's quality",
    21: "4: Expand, expand, expand",
    24: "Clear forest. Make land. Fresh blood. On hands",
    25: "5: Why just shells, why limit yourself?",
    26: "She sells sea shells, sell oil as well",
    27: "6: Guns, sell stocks",
    28: "Sell diamonds, sell rocks",
    29: "Sell the water to a fish, sell the time to a clock",
    30: "7: Press on the gas take your foot of the brakes",
    31: "Then run to be the president of the United States",
    32: "8: Big smile mate, big wave, that's great",
    33: "Now the truth is overrated, tell lies out the gate",
    34: "9: Polarize the people, controversy is the game",
    35: "It don't matter if they hate you if they all say your name",
    36: "Ten.",
    37: "The world is yours.",
    38: "Step out onto a stage to a round of applause",
    39: "You're a liar, a cheat, a devil, a whore",
    40: "and you sell sea shells on the sea shore.",

}


@goofbot.command()
async def givecolorrole(channel, name):
    await channel.send("name of role?")
    rolename = await goofbot.wait_for('message')
# unfinished


@goofbot.command()
async def speedofsound(channel):
    for lyric in soslyrics:
        await channel.send(soslyrics.get(lyric))
        await asyncio.sleep(0.50)


@goofbot.command()
async def seashells(channel):
    for lyric in sslyrics:
        await channel.send(sslyrics.get(lyric))
        await asyncio.sleep(0.39)


@goofbot.command()
async def chuckecheese(channel):
    await channel.send('https://www.roblox.com/games/5960943536/Cone-and-Spirits-chuck-e-cheese')
# my friend asked me to make this, please do not question it.

@goofbot.command()
async def helpme(channel):
    await channel.send(
        'Command list (TBIH is my command prefix):\nhelpme (gives you command list)\nspeedofsound (raps speed of sound)\nseashells (raps money game pt2)\nchuckecheese (links to a goofy roblox game)\nMore on the way! Test them out!')


goofbot.run(TOKEN)
```

All these do is send messages, yet no messages are sent to the channel anymore when I test them. I have absolutely no idea why this is going on because they have worked before.

Edit: So I just realized that I made a silly mistake when implementing `await goofbot.process_commands(message)`.

I assumed that you were supposed to add it before all of the commands so that it would process them, so I added it at the top of my first command so it would affect the rest below instead of putting it in `on_message`. Because I put it in the wrong function, nothing happened.

After realizing this, I quickly put it into the correct function and it worked again.

Comment: can you throw some logs into the mix ? `import logging` ; `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)`

Comment: Sorry it took so long, but yes, I added this code: logging.basicConfig(filename='tbih_log',filemode='w',level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelno)s - %(message)s') to my script, right below my import statements. This is what was shown in the file after I used each command while the bot was running: https://imgur.com/YZ9NG41. Nothing really related to the commands.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code at all. You said in your `on_message()` event you added `await goofbot.process_commands(message)` with no luck. There's not really any reason for this not to be working and works fine with me copy pasting your code. All I could say is making sure you're calling the commands in discord correctly as in messaging `TBIHspeedofsound` with no space. If you could tell us the version of your discord.py and show us your `on_message` event we can try get to the bottom of this